# SNMP AgentX: Howto register for OIDs?

Tags: c++, snmp, net-snmp, oid, mib

I'm writing an AgentX sub-agent for Net-SNMP in C++.

I try to register for the OID  1.3.6.1.4.1.4711.1.1 like this

```
oid myOID[] = { 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 4711, 1, 1 };
handler = netsnmp_create_handler_registration("foo", handler, myOID, OID_LENGTH(myOID), HANDLER_CAN_RONLY);
if (handler)
    netsnmp_register_scalar(handler);
```

Strangely snmpget fails for 1.3.6.1.4.1.4711.1.1 and my handler only gets called when I do snmpget for 1.3.6.1.4.1.4711.1.1.0 (added zero).

How can I register for 1.3.6.1.4.1.4711.1.1 ?

The examples on net-snmp.org all register an instance variable, but I have to run some code to collect the value.

Do I have to declare my callback as extern "C" from a C++ application ?

Does anybbody have an example how to register for all OIDs below 1.3.6.1.4.1.4711.1 so I don't have to define so many handlers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is an unsupported use case of SNMP and may not be possible using the Net-SNMP libraries (although I'm not certain that you can't hack your way to glory and make it work).

The reason it's unsupported is that scalars (or, stated another way, not tables) are by definition supposed to end in `base_oid.0`.  Tables, on the other hand, end in the index of the table entry: `base_oid.1` indicates that you're viewing the entry in the table with an index of `1`.

If you still need to have the OID end in `.1` instead of `.0`, a supported option would be to register a table handler instead.